# D3: order of selections: style and text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, selection

The following two snippets produce different output:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(dataset).enter().append("p")
  .style("color", function(d) {
    if (d > 10) {
      return "red";
    } else {
      return "black";
    }
  })
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

and

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p").data(dataset).enter().append("p")
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
  .style("color", function(d) {
    if (d > 10) {
      return "red";
    } else {
      return "black";
    }
  })
```

The first one generates numbers with different colors (with a specific dataset array), while the second one shows nothing on the screen.

Since dot functions in D3 mostly return selection references, why would the snippets not generate the same DOM content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, In your both snippets, you used 'stype' instead of 'style' for changing color of text
Secondly, There is no difference in first and second snippet. Both will generate same output. but if you are writing both in your code then you will get only one output. as data is already bound with DOM.
For getting multiple output, you can select elements with different classes instead of "p" element.
Here is an example:

```js
d3.select("body").selectAll("p.firstDiv").data(data).enter().append("p")
  .style("color", function(d) {
    if (d > 10) {
      return "red";
    } else {
      return "black";
    }
  })
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
  
  d3.select("body").selectAll("p.secondDiv").data(data).enter().append("p")
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
  .style("color", function(d) {
    if (d > 10) {
      return "red";
    } else {
      return "black";
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you refresh the content before running the 2nd script. If you refresh before running either one, both scripts will give you same result.
Or did you empty the text content after running the 1st script and tried to run the 2nd one?
If so, then nothing will show on the screen as enter() will already see required number of paragraph elements and will not do anything.
If you try to update text and color manually using the snippet shown below (and similar to your 2nd snippet), you will get your desired result.

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
.text(function(d) { return d; })
.style("color", function(d) {
  if (d > 10)
    return "red";
  else 
    return "black";
})
```